# What to use Requisition Scrips for in Star Wars Uprising?

Tags: ios, star-wars-uprising

The only use I found for is the Requisition Scrip Crane in the Supplies screen. But it only holds really bad items which would only be of use for a very low level player. Of course I can claim those random junk items and salvage them for materials/crystals.
I by now have 200 Requisition Scripts and it seems to be more work than of use to claim 200 random items and salvage them...

Any better use for the Requisition Scrips?

Answer (score 1):

Mass salvage. pulling 10 at a time wont take you that long tho, then mass salvage, then merge all the components. You need all those base level components to merge so you can upgrade your good gear.

Comment: I did it a few times now. Important info is, you do not only get those items listed in the crane. You can get wide variety of lower level items. I completed all the basic armor sets with this crane, which unlocked all the blueprints and therefore the upgrades for my crew.